# Simple way to get days given start and end dates

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime

Is there a rapid and simple way to obtain a `List<DateTime>` given start and end dates?

I obviously know that I can achieve this by a loop, but I'm wondering if there is a smarter method using Linq or some other utility.

**NOTE** I need to get a `DateTime` instance **for every single day** between two given dates.

Comment: You want to put two dates in a list...? `new List<DateTime>{ dateTime1, dateTime2 };`

Comment: What kind of granularity are you looking for?

Comment: @MrLister I need a `DateTime` per day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this to get a list from `startDate` to `endDate`:

```
List<DateTime> dates =
  Enumerable.Range(0, (int)((endDate - startDate).TotalDays) + 1)
  .Select(n => startDate.AddDays(n))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: This assumes the interval is an integer number of days, as opposed to say 12 hours, or 3 minutes, or 3.5 days, etc.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, exactly as specified in the question.

Comment: He added that in an edit; before it didn't specify a one day interval.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, that was added before I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Iterator blocks are great for this.

I see no reason not to use a `for` loop here for this.  You need to perform some operator for each date, given that you have that many outputs, no method will have any better asymptotic complexity.

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate
    , TimeSpan interval)
{
    for (DateTime date = startDate; date < endDate; date.Add(interval))
    {
        yield return date;
    }
}
```

You can add an overload for a fixed interval as well:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDays(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return GetDates(startDate, endDate, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lazy evaluated query might look like:

```
//inclusive start and inclusive end
public IEnumerable<DateTime> DateSequence(DateTime start, TimeSpan interval, DateTime end)
{
    DateTime current = start;
    while(current <= end)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.Add(interval);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply use it like following. To get every day set interval to  `TimeSpan.FromDays(1)`

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
var end = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
var interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

var sequence = DateSequence(start, interval, end);

//LinqPad specific call
sequence.Dump();
```

prints:

```
1/14/2013 5:34:57 PM 
1/15/2013 5:34:57 PM 
1/16/2013 5:34:57 PM 
1/17/2013 5:34:57 PM 
1/18/2013 5:34:57 PM 
1/19/2013 5:34:57 PM 
1/20/2013 5:34:57 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want daily granularity, and include the start and end dates:

```
var start = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01);
var end = new DateTime(2013, 01, 01);
var daysInBetween = Enumerable.Range(0, (int) (end - start).TotalDays + 1)
                              .Select(value => start.AddDays(value));
```